# Citrix won't launch java apps on JDK anymore, only JRE

Tags: java, citrix

My company has been running java apps in JDK for years.  In production, the apps are accessed through citrix, and we always have installed the JDK in citrix to run the apps.

Lately, we are finding that citrix will not allow us to launch the java apps when the citrix server's JAVA_HOME is set to a JDK...but will launch them fine with the JRE.  Specifically, JDK 1.8.261_64 won't work, but JDK 1.8.251_64 works, as does JRE 1.8.261_64.   Since we need to be on 1.8.261, I guess we need to convert to JRE.

Outside of citrix, these same apps launch indifferent to JRE vs JDK.

Does anyone know of this change or any reason for the difference?  I've tried searching the internet and asking other programmers, but cannot find any information.

Thanks!